# Wrap string using `sed`

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I need one help to get output as below,

```
b=`'1,2,3,4,5,6' | <using sed>`

echo $b
```

value of `b` I expect as below:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please *try* to do your homework, then post your code.

Comment: `b="$(echo '1,2,3,4,5,6' |grep -o '[0-9],[0-9]')"` will do it with grep, but that's not sed and you haven't specified what you expect from `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1\n/g' <<< "1,2,3,4,5,6"
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

Also you should read [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) at the bash FAQ (It applies even if you're not using bash)

Answer (score 1):

The next solution can fail:

```
# Wrong:  
echo "1,2,3,4,5,6" | grep -Eo "[^,]+,[^,]*"
# Works here, but fails for "1,2,,4,5,6"
```

Perhaps better for your situation is

```
echo "1,2,3,4,5,6" | tr "," "\n" | paste -d"," - -
```